# Server requesting DNS lookup for a box that doesn't exist

Tags: dns, tcpdump

How do I find out which service is making this request?

It's making the requests a lot. Like multiple times a second. I've got a tcpdump and wireshark that shows the info, but I don't know how to find out which process is making the request.

Ok. More info. Sorry

These are all internal to our network. From the network logs on the DNS server I saw that I was getting multiple requests from one of our servers for a dns lookup.

After ssh'ing into the server and running tcpdump -nt udp port 53 and host our dns server ip I can see that indeed this machine is making multiple requests per second for a lookup of an address that is clearly a typo: a-vvs1-s33-1.domain.com.domain.com

I'm trying to isolate which process is making the request.

Comment: You need to put some details in your question about your network setup. How do you know there's a "server" making DNS requests, where are you sampling that network traffic. What do you mean by "a box that doesn't exist"? Are you managing a server or is this domestic, is it local network or over the internet? Why can't you trace it from the IP address in the tcpdump?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in this site.  It would be helpful to other users trying to provide an answer to your problem if you would edit your question and include the exact message that is being displayed.

Comment: I had [a similar problem](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321753) a few years ago. In my case it was samba (nmbd), and because I was using a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Does running `lsof -i` on the requesting server help you find the process making all of the requests?

```
$ sudo lsof -i # Show all services with open ports
$ sudo lsof -i ":53" -P # Limit to all services on port 53
```

`lsof` shows open files.  `lsof`'s `-i` flag limits the results to those with Internet addresses (ie: open sockets).  You can further restrict the list of processes returned by giving `-i` a restriction.  In the second example, `:53` stands for port 53, and the `-P` flag tells `lsof` **not** to convert the port number to a string representing what that port is used for by default (ie: dhcp, ssh, https, etc).

Note: Port 53 is typically used for DNS traffic.

Comment: I think you meant to write: Port 53 is typically used for DNS traffic.